# Установка MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

При установке MySQL сервер появляется данное окно, но кнопки Next нету и дальше ничего не могу сделать, было у кого такое? Как решилось?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваши коллеги по несчастью https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516968/8-0-11-installer-error-authenticatioin-method

Comment: `Alt+N` попробуйте, либо размер шрифтов в винде установите в 100%, у вас вероятно 125%

Comment: спасибо, помогло нажатие клавиш

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как компиляция ответов с [англоязычного сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44074385/1216425)

> Используйте <kbd>Alt + N</kbd> для кнопки *Next*, <kbd>Alt + X</kbd> для *Execute* и  <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> для *Finish*.

или

> Установите размер шрифта в Windows в 100%

Вообще на самом деле подобные проблемы часто встречаются, когда в винде установлен крупный шрифт.

Comment: Да, шрифт был в 125%, спасибо